# Get MS-Windows Installed Applications from Java

Tags: java

Is it possible to get a list of installed applications (like the list from the un-install programs) from a windows vista computer with java?

Comment: What do you mean by "application list"?

Comment: I think he means the list of running applications as listed in the task manager. That or the list of installed programs listed when you want to uninstall a program.

Comment: vote to close as "Not a real question"  Rafiq, please explain what do you mean with "application list"

Comment: @Rafiq, sure is. @Jack's answer says it all.

Comment: If you can get the application list from windows vista with C, then you can get it with java.  You may need to access the list via the JNI API.

Comment: what i mean by application list is all the applications installed on the computer or at least some of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Not a Solution but a workaround!!**

Getting windows native information using java SDK is not possible without support of external APIs. Instead of using external APIs (which is mostly LGPL licensed and not completely open), we can use the shell commands to get the same.

For getting the installed softwares list, use ProcessBuilder or Runtime.exec to run one of the following PowerShell commands:

1. `Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Product | Select-Object -Property Name` - This is bit slower! It uses Win32_Product class.
2. `Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate`  - This is faster and can give additional details. This uses PS registry provider.

You can stream the output of these and process it.

This is just a workaround and it is as per my analysis. As java is completely platform independent, fetching native information becomes difficult and the use of platform native tools (like command shell,, power shell etc.,) is a must.

Comment: Shouldn't the second command be `Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate`?

Comment: Yeah thank you!! Mistakenly typed. The commands are
1. "Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Product | Select-Object -Property Name" (This is bit slower! It uses Win32_Product class).
2. Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate

Answer (score 4):

If you mean installed applications I don't think it's possible by directly using Java SDK (also because it's not a cross platform requirement).. what I think you can do is to use an external native API to interact with windows registry (like [jRegistryKey](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jregistrykey/)) and retrieve the information you need..

Instead if you want to get all the running applications from a Java program you could parse `tasklist.exe` output as explained [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0593.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
package Vishal;

import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32Util;
import static com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinReg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class GenerateInstalledApplicationList 
{
    ArrayList<String> getlist()
    {
        ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList();
        String [] keys = Advapi32Util.registryGetKeys(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall");
    String temp;
    for (String key : keys) 
    {
        temp = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall" + "\\" +key;
        TreeMap<String, Object> tr = Advapi32Util.registryGetValues(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,temp); 
        if(tr.isEmpty())
        {
            if(!key.contains("Update"))//all the instances of update are not actually installed applications
            {
            arr.add(key);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(tr.containsKey("DisplayName"))
            {
                String str = (String) tr.get("DisplayName");
                if(!str.contains("Update"))
                {
                arr.add(str);
                }
            }
        }     
    }
    return arr;
   }}
```

Just Copy and paste this code it will return all the installed applications
only thing you will need is the jna api.

Comment: I get this error "JNativeHook Dispatch Thread" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.sun.jna.Pointer.<init>(J)V from class com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinReg$HKEY