# Get Installed software list

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get MS-Windows Installed Applications from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146576/get-ms-windows-installed-applications-from-java)

how to get the installed software list in windows using java.By using c# i got the solution but how to do using java?

Comment: You have to use JNI. It is platform dependent.

Comment: Already answered here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146576/get-ms-windows-installed-applications-from-java

Answer (score 1):

Java is usually not a bood choice if you want to do platform specific things, like e.g. getting a list of installed applications.

Getting the list means that you need to execute native code, or find a library that does it for you. You can't get that list using only JSE.

Comment: Thank  you ......is it possible using.